# Adding multiple database in Django project

Tags: python, django, multiple-databases

I tried maybe 100 samples but multiple database never worked in my projects. Please help me. I have tired more codes from various sites, but there is last codes in my project which I got from official website. All is the same with the Documentation but still not working.

Settings.py

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['MyApp.routers.TenantRouter']
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'tenant': 'tenant'}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'host_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '******'
    },
   'tenant': {
        'NAME': 'tenant_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '******'
    }
}
```

Routers.py

```
class TenantRouter:
    route_app_labels = {'tenant'}

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'tenant_data'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return 'tenant_data'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels or
            obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
           return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == 'tenant_data'
        return None
```

OneApp/models.py

```
class UserTbl(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Meta:
    app_label = 'tenant'
    db_table = u'UserTbl'
```

And using below line for migrate. But not migrating anything. It always says `No migrations to apply.`

```
python3 manage.py migrate --database=tenant
```

Answer (score 0):

No migrations to apply means your project don't have any migrations files.

first you have to run `python3 manage.py makemigrations OneApp` it will create a migration file inside your OneApp/migrations directory then re-run `python3 manage.py migrate OneApp --database=tenant`
 command.

Comment: Hi Umesh, thanks for your help. I think my question is not enough clear. I understood it after found this github sample [link](https://github.com/nabinbhusal80/multiple-database-implementation-in-django/tree/master/app2). I see router file created under the app folder in this sample. But I created router file in the same folder with settings. I moved it under the app(OneApp) folder and changed below parts `app_label = 'OneApp'` in model, `route_app_labels = {'OneApp'}` in router, `DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['OneApp.routers.TenantRouter']` and it worked.